# Fetching data to table from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm new to programming and codeigniter,

I'm passing an array to view from controller and when i use print_r function i can view the array data in view 
but i want them to show in a table but gives error as "Message: Undefined index: pid....."

my codes are below:

**Controller:**

```
public function bill_data()
{
    $data['data2'] = array(
        'pid' => $this->input->post('pid[]'),
        'proname' => $this->input->post('proname[]'),
        'uprice' => $this->input->post('uprice[]'),
        'qty' => $this->input->post('qty[]'),
        'total' => $this->input->post('total[]'),
        'discount' => $this->input->post('discount'),
        'subtotal' => $this->input->post('subtotal'),
    );

    foreach ($data as $entry) {

        $discount = $entry['discount'];
        $subtotal = $entry['subtotal'];
        $pid = $entry['pid'];
        $proname = $entry['proname'];
        $uprice = $entry['uprice'];
        $qty = $entry['qty'];
        $total = $entry['total'];


    }

    $subtotal = $subtotal - $discount;
    $d['final_result'] = compact("pid", "proname", "uprice", "qty", "total", "discount", "subtotal");

    $this->load->view("invoice", $d);

}
```

**my view is like below:**

```
<?php foreach ($final_result as $row) { ?>
<table class="table m-t-30">
   <thead class="bg-faded">
      <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Product Name</th>
         <th>Unit Price</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['pid']; ?></td>
         <td>dsfdfsdf</td>
         <td>upprice</td>
         <td>qty</td>
         <td>Total</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Why it gives me an error? if i use print_r in view i can see the datas perfectly in view

**Result:**

[image: print_r result and error is with this image]

Comment: print the result and show us, what is getting printed

Comment: @Exprator Sorry for the trouble screenshot added

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately we can't help you troubleshoot your code unless you reduce it to a [Minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NamelessOne dude, there is nothing to reduce, if your brain is unable to process this simple code snippet, then just plz stay out

Comment: @Auris it seems like OPs question not about how to write PHP, but rather asking us to fix his/her code for them. That is off-topic for SO. They need to troubleshoot their own code. Also insulting others' intelligence on SO can lead to flagging. Don't be rude.

Comment: SO is for troubleshooting, helping and asking questions. Honestly out of all the StackExchange sites SO has the most toxic community because ppl start downvoting and closing questions they dont like. Maybe instead of being smug and covering yourself with SO policiestry helping the guy. Maybe that way he will learn something and the whole community will become just that little bit better

Comment: [SO is not for general "troubleshooting"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ... must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. ... See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."
I referred OP to the MCVE page in a friendly way, whereas you simply insulted my intelligence. I don't think that policies are what is wrong with SO. If you dislike these policies rather go to a random Q&A site that is flooded with truckloads of duplicate bad questions.

Comment: Yes, maybe I tend to answer "bad" questions, but the policies do not stop SO from having so many duplicates either, and that is because instead of helping the OP or pointing him to the correct answer written previously, ppl just start throwing SO regulations. Oh and btw i appologise for insulting you, but this kind of burocratic behavior really sets me off, If you are here to help, then help, if you want to be dealing with burocracy, go to politics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your are using foreach. Your "pid" is a top level key. If you foreach your result array your $row will be the individual values not another arrays.

You have 2 options here:

1) remove the foreach iterator in the view

2) wrap your result in array:

```
$d['final_result'][] = compact("pid", "proname", "uprice", "qty", "total", "discount", "subtotal");
```

the option you need will depend on whether you will have more data sets or only one, if it's only one then just remove the foreach in your view.

Also keep in mind that `<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>` will not work as you 'pid' is an array.

Comment: it give more datas not one
so please give the the correct code to fetch this

Comment: Unfortunately writing the correct code is up to you, we can help you find your mistake, but not write your project.

Comment: it come with more datas not with one

Answer (score 0):

First print_r your $row variable then check what indexes are coming and confirm pid index is exist or not

Comment: it give an error
A PHP Error was encountered


Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: row


Filename: views/invoice.php


Line Number: 81